# C# item Drag Fix

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, drag-and-drop

I move three controls using this code on `MouseMove` Event :

```
if (inHareket)
{
    GelenResimcik.Left = e.X + GelenResimcik.Left -MouseDownLocation.X;
    GelenResimcik.Top = e.Y + GelenResimcik.Top - MouseDownLocation.Y;
    GelenResimcik.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
    ResimHareket.Left = e.X + ResimHareket.Left - MouseDownLocation.X;
    ResimHareket.Top = e.Y + ResimHareket.Top - MouseDownLocation.Y;
    Yonlendir.Left = e.X + Yonlendir.Left - MouseDownLocation.X;
    Yonlendir.Top = e.Y + Yonlendir.Top - MouseDownLocation.Y;

    Aktar.Left = e.X + Aktar.Left - MouseDownLocation.X;
    Aktar.Top = e.Y + Aktar.Top - MouseDownLocation.Y;

    Vazgec.Left = e.X + Vazgec.Left - MouseDownLocation.X;
    Vazgec.Top = e.Y + Vazgec.Top - MouseDownLocation.Y;
}
```

and if I try move them faster the result is : [image]

Notice : When i stop moving, the glow is not visible, it is only moving faster.

What shall I do?

EDIT : 
My Controls

```
this.Yonlendir = new System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox();
this.Vazgec = new System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox();
this.Aktar = new System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox();
this.ResimHareket = new System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox();
this.GelenResimcik = new System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox();
```

My Init :

```
        ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.Yonlendir)).BeginInit();
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.Vazgec)).BeginInit();
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.Aktar)).BeginInit();
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.ResimHareket)).BeginInit();
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.GelenResimcik)).BeginInit();
            this.SuspendLayout();
  // 
            // Yonlendir
            // 
            this.Yonlendir.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(40)))), ((int)(((byte)(40)))), ((int)(((byte)(40)))));
            this.Yonlendir.Cursor = System.Windows.Forms.Cursors.Arrow;
            this.Yonlendir.Image = global::Surface.Properties.Resources.rotate;
            this.Yonlendir.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(26, 74);
            this.Yonlendir.Name = "Yonlendir";
            this.Yonlendir.Padding = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(5);
            this.Yonlendir.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(30, 30);
            this.Yonlendir.SizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
            this.Yonlendir.TabIndex = 14;
            this.Yonlendir.TabStop = false;
            this.Yonlendir.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.Yonlendir_Click);
            // 
            // Vazgec
            // 
            this.Vazgec.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(40)))), ((int)(((byte)(40)))), ((int)(((byte)(40)))));
            this.Vazgec.Cursor = System.Windows.Forms.Cursors.Arrow;
            this.Vazgec.Image = global::Surface.Properties.Resources.iptal;
            this.Vazgec.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(93, 8);
            this.Vazgec.Name = "Vazgec";
            this.Vazgec.Padding = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(5);
            this.Vazgec.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(30, 30);
            this.Vazgec.SizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
            this.Vazgec.TabIndex = 13;
            this.Vazgec.TabStop = false;
            this.Vazgec.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.buton1_Click);
            // 
            // Aktar
            // 
            this.Aktar.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(40)))), ((int)(((byte)(40)))), ((int)(((byte)(40)))));
            this.Aktar.Cursor = System.Windows.Forms.Cursors.Arrow;
            this.Aktar.Image = global::Surface.Properties.Resources.kaydet;
            this.Aktar.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(57, 8);
            this.Aktar.Name = "Aktar";
            this.Aktar.Padding = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(5);
            this.Aktar.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(30, 30);
            this.Aktar.SizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
            this.Aktar.TabIndex = 12;
            this.Aktar.TabStop = false;
            this.Aktar.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.Onayla_Click);
            // 
            // ResimHareket
            // 
            this.ResimHareket.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(40)))), ((int)(((byte)(40)))), ((int)(((byte)(40)))));
            this.ResimHareket.Cursor = System.Windows.Forms.Cursors.Arrow;
            this.ResimHareket.Image = global::Surface.Properties.Resources.hareket;
            this.ResimHareket.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(26, 38);
            this.ResimHareket.Name = "ResimHareket";
            this.ResimHareket.Padding = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(5);
            this.ResimHareket.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(30, 30);
            this.ResimHareket.SizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
            this.ResimHareket.TabIndex = 11;
            this.ResimHareket.TabStop = false;
            this.ResimHareket.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.ResimHareket_Click);
            this.ResimHareket.MouseDown += new System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler(this.ResmiHareket_MouseDown);
            this.ResimHareket.MouseMove += new System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler(this.ResmiHareket_MouseMove);
            this.ResimHareket.MouseUp += new System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler(this.ResimHareket_MouseUp);
            // 
            // GelenResimcik
            // 
            this.GelenResimcik.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(0)))), ((int)(((byte)(0)))), ((int)(((byte)(0)))), ((int)(((byte)(0)))));
            this.GelenResimcik.BackgroundImageLayout = System.Windows.Forms.ImageLayout.None;
            this.GelenResimcik.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(57, 39);
            this.GelenResimcik.Name = "GelenResimcik";
            this.GelenResimcik.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(438, 452);
            this.GelenResimcik.SizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.PictureBoxSizeMode.AutoSize;
            this.GelenResimcik.TabIndex = 2;
            this.GelenResimcik.TabStop = false;
```

My Timer (Interval 100):

```
  private void ResimKontrol_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                if (ontanimli.Height != 0)
                {
                    GelenResimcik.Image = ontanimliGelen;
                    GelenResimcik.Parent = cizim;
                    entegreGoster();

                  }
            }
            catch
            {

            }

        }
```

entegreGoster and entegreGizle

```
public void entegreGoster() { GelenResimcik.BringToFront();ResimHareket.BringToFront();Aktar.BringToFront();Vazgec.BringToFront(); Yonlendir.BringToFront(); }
        public void entegreGizle() { GelenResimcik.SendToBack(); ResimHareket.SendToBack(); Aktar.SendToBack(); Vazgec.SendToBack(); Yonlendir.SendToBack(); }
```

My MouseDown event :

```
 private void ResmiHareket_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            MouseDownLocation = e.Location;
            inHareket = true;
        }
```

I start timer when Open new form

```
Ontanimlilar ontanimli = new Ontanimlilar();
            ontanimli.Show();
            ResimKontrol.Start();
```

ontanimliGelen (public static pictureBox)

ontanimli  Class :

```
Ciz.ontanimliGelen = seciliRes.Image;
this.Close();
```

Comment: Force the client area to redraw itself. Use the `Invalidate` member function.

Comment: @CodyGray like GelenResimcik.Invalidate(); ?? It's didn't work

Comment: Show your drawing code.

Comment: @LarsTech I'm not drawing they are pixturebox

Comment: Then you aren't showing us enough of your code that reproduces the problem for us.

Comment: @LarsTech I edit my Q.